# How can I modify Theme.Holo.Light.Dialog to take up less screen space?

Tags: android, android-theme

My app is currently using the Holo Light theme, except where I've added customizations. This is mostly OK, but I'm having difficulty with styling the Dialog box.

The holo theme has the colours I want, but `Theme.Dialog` is more compact, i.e. it takes up less space on the screen which is what I also want.

When I use the Holo theme, with the following customisation

```
  <style name="AlertDialogCustom" parent="@android:style/Theme.Holo.Light.Dialog">
    <item name="android:buttonStyle">@style/general_button_style</item>
    <item name="android:textColor">@color/my_blue</item>
  </style>
```

it appears like this:

[image]

When I revert the dialog box to the non-Holo theme

```
  <style name="AlertDialogCustom" parent="@android:style/Theme.Dialog">
    <item name="android:buttonStyle">@style/general_button_style</item>
    <item name="android:textColor">@color/my_blue</item>
  </style>
```

it appears as follows:

[image]

What do I need to change to use the holo theme but to make it use less screen space?

Answer (score 0):

The extra space used in Holo theme is used to accomodate for scrolling effect when you swipe up or down.

Both of the scrolling components are sitting inside of a view like **[this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5xZCl.png)**.

Specifying negative margins on top/bottom of both components should do the (although dirty) trick:

```
<TimePicker
    android:id="@+id/timePicker1"
    ...
    android:layout_marginBottom="-20dip"
    android:layout_marginTop="-20dip"/>
```

Play with the numbers as needed as I didn't try it myself.